# Does not setting a wifi password allow malware to more easily jump between computers?

Tags: wireless-networking, passwords, malware

Does not setting a wifi password allow malware to more easily jump between computers?

(Some users don't set wifi passwords if intruders aren't able to get within range of their wifi.)

Comment: Malware doesn't jump, it walks in with downloads, email, browsing infected web sites, etc.  That's not the primary reason for a wifi password.  The password is to definitively control who can access the system as opposed to relying on people to be too far away.  The password is needed once per session and takes seconds to enter, so there is no good reason to not use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that an intruder is not able to get within the range, then no password is needed. Another option to control the access to your local network is filtering by MAC address.

But once your computer is connected to the network, malware can infect your computers regardless of having a password for your network: virus, trojans, etc. will infect your computer when you download a file, connect to a P2P system, use the e-mail etc.

Answer (score 0):

Some worms can jump to other computer (scan for network shared with write access), but it can at most copy itself to directory of other PC in the same network, not execute. This work is not bounded with WiFi unprotected networks, but your connection to network, where are others PCs. Worms are spreading by their definition.

Unprotected WiFi networks are untrustworthy because it can be provided by another user, who can filter your traffic and do a Man-in-the-middle attack.